# Where are the docker images?

Tags: docker, image, filesystems

I created an image on local laptop:

```
% docker build -t kubia .
```

But where is it?

```
ls: /var/lib/docker/: No such file or directory
```

- it's not here

```
% ls \~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0
00000002\.00001003  connect         data            hyperkit.json       log
00000003\.000005f5  console-ring        guest.000005f5      hyperkit.pid
```

- not here either

When I write a

```
docker images
```

where do I get the output from?

Comment: If it was successfully built, it should be listed when we run `docker image ls` (`docker image ls | grep -i kubia`).

Comment: It'll be in Docker-internal storage; the exact location and format depend on the host OS, Docker installation, and some additional configuration options.  You can't access it directly.

Comment: There is no problem to see the presence of the image.

Would like to know where it is. Can't access directly - what does that mean?

Comment: I don't expect a directory path. I expect some clarification about the details of docker isolation on MacBook.